# Question inside answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question: [Spliterator implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52050/spliterator-implementation) got two answers. Into one of these, there's a question for me:

> one of the performance advantages of Spliterator is the forEachRemaining() method, and you have chosen not to implement it. Why?

What's the best way to handle it? A comment or an edit? A comment would be better since future readers can follow chronological evolution of the thread.  An edit would be better since I can explain better (more chars, more formatting) but future readers will lose how the final review was formed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In such a case, a comment below their answer would be better.  If a longer discussion is needed if there are too many comments (and the system will let you know if that happens), it can be taken to chat, and future readers can still follow that.

On the other hand, an edit would not be recommended because *questions shouldn't be updated based on answers*.  They should also not be edited with responses to questions from answers, as that's not what the question is supposed to communicate.

Comment: Adding clarification to a question is fine. Modifying the code in a question in response to an answer is not.